# Setting response from axios to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

When I try to setState after the get axios request it doesn't seem that I have the data ready to render.In console, I am getting a response but unable to access the response in the state.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-flexbox-grid';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import stylefile from './stylefile';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import '../App.css';

class TitleBar extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state ={
            data:[],
        }
      }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://api.abc',
            {
                headers: { "Postman-Token": "abc"}
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                this.setState({
                    data: response.data,
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    console.log(this.state.data,"data response")
    return (
        <div>
            {
                this.state.data.map(((item,key) => (
                 <div>
                     //
                 </div>
             )))}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(stylefile)(TitleBar);
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

//console.log(this.state.data) -- is undefined

Comment: Where and how do you check the state like that?

Comment: Take care about using setState in ComponentWillMount().   When you use setState in there, React WON'T trigger the re-render, then the application wouldn't see the response.data in the state.

Comment: As I said in the comments of the provided answer, I agree with the suggestion here but `componentWillMount` triggers a render if `setState` is done after an async job. This is why I wonder where does OP use `console.log`.

Comment: So, can you see your data in your fetch request? `console.log(response.data);` Also, you are logging it in your `render` method and you say it is `undefined here`, right?

Comment: exactly sir @devserkan

Comment: Can we see this `response.data` log?

Comment: Does my answer help? I think the true reason which make your data `undefined` is that

Comment: {MESSAGE: "List details Fetch successful", STATUS: "SUCCESS", DATA: Array(50), USER: {…}, HASH: "3--0", …} "results"   @devserkan

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú it is still undefined

Comment: I assume this is the `response.data` log, yes?

Comment: yes @devserkan for response.data and for this.state.data also because i am setting state

Comment: TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function

Comment: Ok, if this is the `response.data` then it means this is not an array and the real data you want probably is `response.data.DATA`. So, set your state according to that: `this.setState( { data: response.data.DATA } )`. Though, you should be able to see an empty array instead of `undefined`, weird.

Comment: Ah, sorry my bad. It is normal it is an `undefined` here. I will provide an answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Sorry, code snippet hit me with an absurd error. It is a little bit more than "a few minutes" :) but I provided a simple answer. If none of the answers help you, we can discuss this in a chat discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Your API response object includes an object like:

```
const response = {
  data: {
    MESSAGE: "List details Fetch successful",
    STATUS: "SUCCESS",
    DATA: [
      { id: 1, name: "foo" },
      { id: 2, name: "bar" },
      { id: 3, name: "baz" }
    ],
    HASH: "3--0"
  }
};
```

So, you need `response.data.DATA` for your state here:

```
this.setState( { data: response.data.DATA } );
```

Here is a working example of mimicking your situation.

```js
const remoteData = {
  data: {
    MESSAGE: "List details Fetch successful",
    STATUS: "SUCCESS",
    DATA: [
      { id: 1, name: "foo" },
      { id: 2, name: "bar" },
      { id: 3, name: "baz" },
    ],
    HASH: "3--0",
  },
};

const fakeRequest = () =>
  new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( () => resolve( remoteData ), 1000 ) );

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fakeRequest().then( response => this.setState( { data: response.data.DATA } ) );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map( el => (
          <div key={el.id}>
            <p>{el.id}</p>
            <p>{el.name}</p>
          </div>
        ) )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById( "root" )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From [React official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount),

> componentWillMount() is invoked just before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore calling setState() synchronously in this method will not trigger an extra rendering

Also,one should use `componentDidMount` as `componentWillMount` is deprecated in new version of react.

```
componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://api./abc',
            {
                headers: { "Postman-Token": "abc" }
            })
            .then((response) => { //use arrow to get setState on this call without any extra binding or placeholder variable
                console.log(response.data);
                this.setState({
                    data: response.data,
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
```

Comment: I agree with `componentDidMount` suggestion but OP is updating the state with an async job, so after this point, it triggers a rerender.

Comment: i am getting error while i am mapping ..  like his.state.data.map is not a function
                this.state.data.map(((item,key) => (
                 <div>
                     
                 </div>

Comment: @SupriyaBhart, please update your question with your whole component code.

Comment: @SupriyaBhart its look like `response.data` is not an array.Please check response structure

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN, I suspected that also but in any case, it must not be `undefined` in the logs, I mean in the `render` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix those lines of code:

```
  constructor(props) { //fixed
    super(props); //fixed
    this.state ={
        data:[],
    }
  }
```

This is just the way ReactJS set up the `constructor()` method for a `class component`. We just obey the React's rules while working with it.

From the [Official React Document](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor), they said:

> The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted. When implementing the constructor for a React.Component subclass, you should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise, this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to bugs.

For more information about the `contructor()` method: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

This is a working example which I've already made just for you as a reference.

The demo is now available on CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/8xvn8yl1l2

`TitleBar.js`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
export default class TitleBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        this.setState({ data: res.data });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map(i => (
          <div key={i.id}>
            <h2>{i.title}</h2>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`App.js`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TitleBar from './components/TitleBar';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TitleBar></TitleBar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

By following this example, if the `this.state.data` is still `undefine`, then there are two things that we could focus on in order to successfully debug:

1.The structure of the response data object. In your case, the solution could be

```
this.setState({
   data: response.data.DATA  
})
```

2.Does the API work as expected.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: yes i think that the response structure @Thankyou sir